# How to get jenkins to launch multiple instances of an AMI?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the EC2 plugin for jenkins and having problems getting multiple instances to spin up. I have one AMI configured and a job configured to use it as the build slave. The AMI is configured to have 1 executor, and the job has a weight of 1. When I kick off a build, it spins up an instance of the AMI as expected and does everything I need it to do, then terminates the instance when it's done. The problem is I would like to be able to kick off multiple concurrent builds of this job at once. I have selected "enable multiple concurrent builds" in the job config, but when I try to kick off a second build it says "pending" because the AMI is already being used by the first build.

When I kick off a second build, I would like it to spin up another instance of the AMI. I know I could copy the AMI and configure it in the EC2 plugin as a second build slave, but I only want to deal with managing one AMI. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the number of executors on the slave machine so that the concurrent jobs get executed. Second option is to set a idle termination time for your slave. You can set 10 minutes idle termination time so that the job which is going into a pending state will be executed and after the concurrent job gets executed, the instance will wait for 10 minutes and if no job is triggered in those 10 minutes, then your instance will be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the **Instance Cap** is more than 1 , it's in the main configuration.

if not , PLS uplodad your configuration  here so we can try and help

Thanks , Mor